# MySQL inner join changes column value

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I found something really confusing recently about inner join:

```
select records.id, 
       records.amount, 
       records.payment_amount, 
       orders.id as or_id 
from `records` 
**`inner`** `join order_from_site orders on records.id = orders.`record_id`
```

will somehow set the **`payment_amount`** value to 0.0.

If however, I change the **`inner`** join to **`left`** join, the value is correctly preserved. Not sure if this is the expected behavior or a bug?

I'm using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: That´s because you don´t have any rows in your **order_from_site** that matches **records.id = orders.record_id**. In the left join, you get all rrows from the left table, even if there is no match with the right table. The inner join get rows only when there is a match

Comment: And your query doesn´t make sense, if records.id = orders.record_id, why do you put them both in the select?? They are equal so you don´t need top repeat the column. And if you don´t select any column from the orders table, why do you join them?

Comment: Ahh, you are right -- just realized this is stupid question. Thanks for taking time to actually answer it :)

Comment: @nacho, It could be to find common elements, also OP, check if the data types of both fields match

Comment: @AdityaShankar, thanks for the advice. @Simon is right. I was under the assumption that there must be records after the join, since there are millions of them with `payment_amount > 0.0`. but it turns out my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not provide any data from the two tables so it will be hard to determine the answer to your question without the data.

That said, an **inner join** requires matched data from both sides to be present in order to display a row. A **left join** requires the table from the left to be present and only optionally on the right.